SDL2 Rumble not working with DS4Windows Xbox Controller
SDL_GameControllerRumble(gControllers[aIndex], 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 2000);

This is the method that I am using for rumble. In the DS4Windows application, I have the Emulated Controller configured to "Xbox 360" and it actually has rumble (tested on https://hardwaretester.com/gamepad) but SDL2 won't make it rumble. But if I set the Emulated Controller to "DualShock 4", it will actually work with SDL2. I don't get what's the problem here.
